# returning results from a column into an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am very new to PHP and I realise I have a lot to learn, especially about SQL injection attacks and the new php 5.5 oo stuff.

However, whilst I am learning I try to play about a bit and experiment and I have come across a problem. I need to get all results from one column (team_name) of my query into an array (zero indexed would be easier) so that I can put those results into a foreach loop to create a fixture list. For example - this is what I would like to do with the data...

```
foreach ($teams as $team) {
    foreach ($teams as $opposition) {
        if ($team != $opposition) {
            echo "$team versus $opposition";
        }
    }
}
```

So my sql query is as follows...

```
$query="select * from pool_a";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Then I can easily output the data I am looking for as follows;

```
echo "<table>";
for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
    $teams=mysql_result($result,$i,'team_name');
      echo "<tr><td>$teams</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

But what I can't do is get the data into an array. I thought that data that came back from a msql_query such as the above always came back as an array, no matter the number of results, but if I run an is_array() check on $teams, it returns false.

I have tried using explode (after adding a comma after each team name and trimming the last one off) and then using a foreach loop but it only ever returns the value associated with the index [0]. I should add here that although the key is 0, the actual value I get is the LAST in the list when echoed as above, which I also don't understand.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $result_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

Comment: does that replace something or an added line of code under existing query? thanks

Comment: Use of `mysql_*` functions is highly discouraged. You should start using MySQLi or PDO for database related tasks ASAP.

Comment: thanks for that. Where would be the best place to read up or learn about the PDO drivers and prepared statements? I think the book I have is a little out of date!

Answer (score 3):

```
$team_names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $team_names[] = $row['team_name'];
}
```

`mysql_fetch_assoc`, `mysql_fetch_row`, and `mysql_fetch_array` all return a row as an array (they differ in how it's indexed). But `mysql_result` just returns a single item from the result, so it doesn't return an array.

You could do the same thing as above with your use of `mysql_result`, but you still have to push them onto the result array yourself:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {
    $team=mysql_result($result,$i,'team_name');
    $team_names[] = $team;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the results of the query into an array, you can do this

```
$query="select * from pool_a";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$result_arr = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

However, consider using the PDO drivers to connect to the database. It's far superior to doing it procedurally, and it's safer as Prepared Statments will help protect you against injection attacks. The method you're using is deprecated.

Comment: thanks for that. Where would be the best place to read up or learn about the PDO drivers and prepared statements? I think the book I have is a little out of date!

Comment: There are many resources on the Web that are just a Google search away. However, I'm going to be a bit biased here, and recommend you go for a decent framework.

I recommend Laravel. It's got a low barrier to entry, a great community, and it's the most popular PHP project on GitHub (and it's only 3 years old). The docs are good, and you can learn a lot from the code. Many folks have written books on the subject too. I don't recommend you just stick to Laravel, but it's an excellent starting point for you to start growing as a PHP developer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mysql_result try using mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)

This function will give you an array of whatever your result from MySQL is.

Comment: But it returns a single row, not a column. He still needs to collect them into an array himself, as shown in my answer.